# WPf : Binding with more than one property at a time

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have a list view in which I use binding to display my information. I use a simple data template. Is there a way to bind two data in one control. What I mean would to be replace something like :

<TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}"/>

<TextBlock Text=", "/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding NName}"/>

to something like

<TextBlock Text="{Binding LName} + ',' + {Binding FName}"/>

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on WPF 3.5SP1 or above, you don't need to write your own value converter for your use case. Instead, just use `StringFormat`:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
      <Binding Path="LName" />
      <Binding Path="FName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Kent: Is there a way to make this binding two-way without a converter, though?  This is great for view, but can you edit?

Comment: @Reed: whoops, I meant `TextBlock`. Updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You would use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) along with an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

The [MultiBinding help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) shows an example doing exactly what you're attempting - binding one text box to first + last names.